# Set style if element have one common common class and another

Tags: css, sass

Is there a way to use SASS/CSS to set a style for an element that has a common class as well as another. For example, I would like the border to appear for elements that are either:

```
<div class="plate eggs"></div>
<div class="plate bacon"></div>
```

but not:

```
<div class="plate"></div>
```

The code I have at the moment but I'm sure there's a way to combine the two rules?

```
.plate {

  border: none;

  &.eggs {

    border: 1px solid red;
  }

  &.bacon {
    border: 1px solid red;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SCSS:

```
.plate {
  border: none;
  &.eggs,&.bacon {
    border: 1px solid red;
  }
}
```

SASS:

```
.plate
  border: none
  &.eggs,&.bacon
    border: 1px solid red
```

You can validate your styles in [sassmeister](https://www.sassmeister.com/).

Comment: Thanks - this is what I had but then it didn't work for me. Perhaps grunt hadn't reloaded the CSS or browser cache.

Answer (score 0):

Why not add another class ? But if that's not the case, I'd use `:not([class])` . Ormaybe even further, you can consider using `div[class^="eggs"]`